# How to take in and sort the array of object and also the number of objects in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Here I want to takes in the array of the object to sort and also the number of objects in the array.

```
public BookRecord [] sortString(BookRecord [] myArray, int noRecords)
```

Like I have tag values ABEW2345, HGNH4567, HJKG2342 in the .txt file. My question is how to implement the selection sort algorithm in this method to sort the object array? 
The only thing I know is after the file was read, the array of BookRecord objects has been created, call the sortString() method. This method would use selection sorting algorithm to re-arrange the objects in the array in a lexicographic increasing order in respect of the tag values.

Comment: so you want someone to write the method for you?

Comment: No. My question is how to implement the selection sort algorithm in this method to sort the object array? How to do that? Which line did I ask someone to write the method for me? Thanks for commenting and voting, anyway.

Comment: ok, so how do you wish to get an answer for "how to implement sort algorithm"? do you want pseudo code? flow diagram? maybe google or qoura is better suited for such broad scoped questions

Comment: here you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation

Answer (score -1):

based on my understanding I suggest

```
public BookRecord[] sortString(BookRecord [] myArray, int noRecords)
{
  //uses sort method of Arrays and simply returns the sorted array
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
    return myArray
}
```

after sorting, to view the values create a for loop to iterate over the Array.

```
public void viewBookRecord(BookRecord[] array)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++){
    System.out.print(array[i])
}
```

Comment: so this answer could be summed in one line that uses stabdard JDK library, and probably should be no more than a comment. look at the question. this is not what was asked for.

Comment: and the answer does not even mention what are the minimum requirements so that an array of user defined class can be sorted